# Error sync pivot Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema y es que al momento de querer actualizar los datos de un usuario con `sync` (para los permisos) me sale un error:

-codigo de la vista de editar:

```
<form action="{{action('Administracion\UsuarioPersonalController@update', $id)}}" method="POST">
{!! method_field('PUT') !!}
@csrf

<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label> Cargos:</label>
    <select id="cargo" class="form-control" name="IdCargo">
        @foreach($cargo as $c)
        @if($empleado->IdCargo == $c->IdCargo)
        <option value="{{$c->IdCargo}}" selected>{{$c->Nombre}}</option>
        @else
        <option value="{{$c->IdCargo}}">{{$c->Nombre}}</option>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label>Seleccionar Perfil:</label>
    <select id="perfiles" class="form-control" name="IdPerfil">
        @foreach($perfil as $p)
        @if($empleado->IdPerfil == $p->IdPerfil)
        <option value="{{$p->IdPerfil}}" selected>{{$p->Nombre}}</option>
        @else
        <option value="{{$p->IdPerfil}}">{{$p->Nombre}}</option>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label>Correo:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Correo" id="" value="{{$empleado->Correo}}">
</div>
<div class="m-form__group form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="">Permisos de Usuario</label>
    @foreach($permiso as $p => $Nombre)
    <label class="m-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{$p}}" {{$empleado->Permisos->pluck('IdPermiso')->contains($p) ? 'checked' : ''}} name="permisos[]">  {{$Nombre}}
    </label>
    @endforeach
</div>
</form>
```

-codigo del Modelo:

```
public function Permisos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permiso::class, 'Asignar_Permisos','IdEmpleado', 'IdPermiso');
    }
```

-codigo del controller donde actualizo:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $empleado = Empleado::where('IdEmpleado', '=', $id)->update([

            'IdCargo' => $request->IdCargo,
            'IdPerfil' => $request->IdPerfil,
            'Correo' => $request->Correo
        ]);
        $empleado->Permisos()->sync($request->permisos);

        return back()->with('Enviado', 'El Usuario Fue');
    }
```

- error que sale:

> Call to a member function Permisos() on int

Por lo que noto, este error sale al momento de querer actualizar los permisos ya que los datos anterior se actualizan normalmente. Soy nuevo usando laravel asi que si un caso esta mal por favor ayudenme en arreglarlo

Comment: Intenta cambiando la P mayuscula por p en miniscula en ambos lugares.

Comment: El método ´update()´ devuelve un `int`, por eso no podés usar `Permisos()`. Qué es lo que querés hacer? El `sync` se lo querés aplicar a todos los empleados con el `IdEmpleado X`? Pueden haber varios o solo uno? Para que tenés la primera línea del `findOrFail()` si después no lo usás para nada? Detallá un poco mejor que querés hacer así te orientamos correctamente.

Comment: @azeós ya agrege un poco mas de descripcion al problema, lo que quiero hacer es actualizar los datos de un usuario pero el problema esta al momento de querer actualizar los permisos de usuario.

Comment: No respondiste mi pregunta. Hay un solo empleado o varios con un `IdEmpleado`?

Comment: @azeós hay varios empleados con IdEmpleado pero mi problema es cuando quiero editar los datos de un solo empleado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [update()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L812) devuelve un `int`, no un objeto `Eloquent` ni una `Collection`, con lo cual, no podes seguir corriéndole métodos.

Asumo que estás trayendo todos los empleados con un `IdEmpleado` y que puede haber más de uno (por lo que dijiste).
Pero no termino de estar seguro, me parece que no tenés más de un empleado con un `IdEmpleado` en particular. Sino la ruta es un tanto confusa y el nombre del campo también.

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    // Traemos todos los empleados con ese ID
    $empleados = Empleado::where('IdEmpleado', $id)->get();

    // Recorremos todos los empleados
    foreach ($empleados as $empleado) {
        $empleado->IdCargo = $request->IdCargo;
        $empleado->IdPerfil = $request->IdPerfil;
        $empleado->Correo = $request->Correo;
        $empleado->save();
        $empleado->Permisos()->sync($request->permisos);
    }

    return back()->with('Enviado', 'El Usuario Fue');
}
```

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, no se si me habre explicado bien o no, es que soy nuevo en esto de laravel y no conozco muy bien algunas cosas pero el punto es que lo que pedia es exactamente lo que tu has respondido, Gracias soluciono el problema

Comment: Me alegro haber ayudado. Para próximas preguntas que tengan alguna relación con la base de datos, ayuda que publiques los archivos de los modelos involucrados o parte de la estructura de la misma.